# writing method that sorts address by postal code using def comesBefore(self, other)

Tags: python, function, class, methods, init

I've got an assignment as follows:
"Supply a method def comesBefore(self, other) that tests whether this address comes before other when compared by postal code. This method should return a boolean value."

This for writing a class that collects the addresses and returns them in order by zip code. He wants us to use the 'def comesBefore(self, other)' method to do so.

I'm not great at python so for the life of me I can't figure out how to get it to work, but here's what I have:

```
Class Address py

#address class
class Address:


    #initializing
    def __init__(self, house_street = '', apt_number = '', city = '', state = '', postal_code = ''):
        self.set_house_street(house_street)
        self.set_city(city)
        self.set_state(state)
        self.set_postal_code(postal_code)
        self.set_apt_number(apt_number)
        
    def __str__(self): #Function to tell str how to deal with Address
        return self.get_full_address()


    #set and capitalize house number and street name
    def set_house_street(self, house_street):
        
        self._house_street = house_street.title()

    #return
    def get_house_street(self, house_street):
        return self._house_street


#optional apt number
    def set_apt_number(self, apt_number = ''): # <- Se a default parameter
    
       self._apt_number = apt_number

#get and return apt number
    def get_apt_number(self, apt_number):
        return self._apt_number


    #set and capitalize city
    def set_city(self, city):
        self._city = city.capitalize()

    #return city
    def get_city(self, city):
        return self._city
    

    #set and capitalize state and only keep the first 2 letters
    def set_state(self, state):

        self._state = state[0:2].upper()

    #return state
    def get_state(self, state):
        return self._state


    #set postal code
    def set_postal_code(self, postal_code):

        self._postal_code = postal_code

    #return postal code
    def get_postal_code(self, postal_code):
        return self._postal_code

    #return the full address
    def get_full_address(self):
        if self._apt_number == '':
            full_address = f'{self._house_street}\n{self._city}, {self._state} {self._postal_code}'
        else:
            full_address = f'{self._house_street}, Apt {self._apt_number}\n{self._city}, {self._state} {self._postal_code}'
        return full_address


#here's where I'm having trouble.
#I've never had to use 'other' before so I'm not quite sure how to properly use it.
#It's supposed to compare the postal codes and sort the addresses in order according to the postal code. 
#This bit of code for this function is what my tutor gave me to work with, and I'm still having trouble understanding it ;-;

    def comesBefore(self, other):
        retVal = False

        if (self._postal_code < postal_code):
            retVal = True

        elif (self.full_address < full_address):
            retVal = True

        return retVal
```

```
Project 4 Test py
from Class_Address import Address

#finding out how many people they want to get the info from
def get_how_many(title):

    #not done is considered true right now, which means we aren't done getting addresses to get info from
    not_done = True
    
    #so while we're not done, we make a try/except program
    while not_done:

        #trying to
        try:
            #get a quanity of 'how many address are we getting?'
            qty = int(input(title))

            #if they input less than 0, we're done and don't need to do anything
            if qty > 0:
                not_done = False

            #otherwise, if they do input <1, display the error
            else:
                print('You must have at least 1 data point to enter. Please try again.')

        #otherwise, print an exception
        except:
            print('Invalid input! Please try again.')

    #return the quantity of addresses
    return qty

#making a list to hold info
def getting_address(how_many):

    #empty list
    address_list = []

    #for each person they want to get info from
    for i in range(how_many):
        #request addresses
        houseStreet = input("What is your address? ")
        aptNum = input("What is your apartment number? ")
        city = input("What is your city? ")
        state = input("What is your state? ")
        postal_code = input("What is your 5 digit postal code? ")
        address_list.append(Address(houseStreet, aptNum, city, state, postal_code)) #<- Need to add to your list

    #return list
    return address_list


#print addresses
def print_address(address_list):
    print("Here are the addresses you've entered:")

    for address in address_list:
       # print(f'{address.get_house_street()} Apt{address.get_apt_number}')
       # print(f'{address.get_city()}, {address.get_state()} {address.get_postal_code()}')
       print(str(address)) #<- Get a string version of hte address and print it.


#main
def main():
    how_many = get_how_many("How many addresses would you like to enter? ")
    address_list = getting_address(how_many)
    print_address(address_list)

#calling main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

All the code runs, I'm just having difficulty implementing the function to sort the addresses by postal code. If anyone could explain how to implement the function into the two py files, that'd be absolutely wonderful!

Comment: I'm not sure what's giving you trouble.  You're just comparing two numbers: the one that's part of this object (`self._postal_code`) and the one that is passed to you as a parameter to compare (`other._postal_code`).  This function doesn't do the sorting -- it will be used by some OTHER routine to decide which of two comes first.

Comment: From [https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#odd-and-ends](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#odd-and-ends): `The sort routines are guaranteed to use __lt__() when making comparisons between two objects. So, it is easy to add a standard sort order to a class by defining an __lt__() method`

Comment: `I've never had to use 'other' before so I'm not quite sure how to properly use it` - what do you think other might be? -what will you be passing to `comesBefore`??

Comment: normally when you do `number < other` then Python may run `number.__lt__(other)` and the same you may have in your code - `other` means `other address` which it will compare and inside code you should use `self._postal_code < other._postal_code`, and `self.full_address < other.full_address`